# HelpNDoc : Problem to generate CHM format help - Error HHC5010

Tags: chm, helpndoc

I would like to generate a CHM help file with HelpNDoc.

But I get an error message:

> HHC5010: Error: Cannot open "c:\users\philippeDocuments\HelpNDoc\Output\chm\creabook.chm". Compilation stopped.

I tried to create the CHM folder myself, in the "Output" folder but no result.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and using Wine as a Windows emulator.
Maybe it's an authorization issue?

What is surprising is that I was able to generate the Word and html documentation.

Is someone can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use Ubuntu or Wine as an environment and would like to recommend a machine with Windows for compiling CHM help files.

Despite the close connection of CHM help files with the Windows operating system, I do not want to completely exclude the possibility of compiling in a Wine environment.

My good old compiler *Error Message Reference* shows the following:

> HHC5010: Cannot open ""file name"". Compilation stopped.
> Problem: The specified file either doesn't exist, or another program has it open and is denying permission to read the file.
> **Result:** The .chm file is corrupt and cannot be used.
> **Solution:** If another program does have the file open, close the program. Otherwise either correct the name in your project file or remove it.

Please make sure that the CHM help file `"c:\users\philippeDocuments\HelpNDoc\Output\chm\creabook.chm"` is not open in Wine's HTML help viewer by using e.g. `wine hh creabook.chm`.

Please also try if you can open another CHM help file in your environment. Maybe you have to specify a windows path, e.g.

```
wine hh.exe `winepatch -w /some/dir/somefile.chm`
```

As mentioned above, this is somewhat problematic outside of Windows.

See also some notes at [Installing Microsoft HTML Workshop under Wine](https://help.k15t.com/scroll-chm-exporter/installing-microsoft-html-workshop-under-wine-93290645.html)

Comment: Issue fixed with a Virtual Box configuration. Thank you for your help ! To generate the CHM document, I had to change too the "output file" construction parameters and specify an easiest URL: c:\doc\doc.chm. More information here :  https://www.helpndoc.com/step-by-step-guides/how-to-define-build-settings-in-helpndoc/